# D3.js: How to get the selection index, instead of the data index?

Tags: d3.js

There are a lot of instances where i need to act upon the index of the element inside it's selection group (update, enter, exit), instead of it's index within the data. How can i get this index?

For example, if i am exiting 4 elements.

```
legends.exit()
    .transition()
    .delay(d=>i*25)
    .style("opacity",0)
```

`i` in this case are [8,12,15,20]. How do i set the index to be [0,1,2,3];

My quick and dirty solution is this. Can i do this within the context of d3?

```
var i = 0;
legends.exit()
    .transition()
    .delay(d=>i++*25)
    .style("opacity",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the following code to your solution:

```
.delay(function(d,i){ return (i-legends.size()); })
```

Alternatively, the following worked in my small test example but I'm not sure why exactly. The `filter` is necessary.

```
legends.exit().filter(function(d){return true;})
    .transition()
    .delay((d,i)=>i*25)
    .style("opacity",0)
```

My best guess would be that applying the filter 'resets' the indexing of the selection.